# How can I ungroup open same programs in panel?

Tags: kali-linux, xfce, desktop-environment, panel

this is my os

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.3
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

this is how it looks open same programs on panel.

[image]

I have 3 vscode instances and they are grouped together. How can I separate them?
I went through entire settings there is no option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open
Panel Preferences -> Items -> Window Buttons

In "Window Buttons" -> Behaviour -> Window grouping = Never

[image: For example]